# Increase in width and height of div on textarea input

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I tried to get the answer. Searched on google too. But unfortunately couldn't get the answer. i have a div with textarea. On keyup i want the div to increase with the text typed and also on enter press div height should increase according to the fontsize. When i press enter width continues to increase from where it had stopped. Check this fiddle and help me out with functionality. 
**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/shabbirrangwala/NkRYY/8/

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {


if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
$('.EDetailInset').css('height', ((this.value.length + 1) * 3) + 'px');

}
else 
{
$('.EDetailInset').css('width', ((this.value.length + 1) * 11) + 'px');

}
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass +=15 as an argument to css function. Try this:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {

    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
        $('.EDetailInset').css('height', "+=30");
    }
    else {
        $('.EDetailInset').css('width', "+=30");
    }
});
```

And I suggest you to read to [read this](http://api.jquery.com/css/#example-1-4) if you want to do more advanced things.

Comment: When i press enter div doesnt reset to the last character. It starts increasing from where it had stopped before pressing enter. That is what i dont want. I want width to pull back to the last character on enter press.

Comment: You can keep the maximum line length in a variable and set the length of your textarea accordingly and if you happen to have a longer line next time you press enter just update the value of the variable.

Comment: Check the answer below and read my last comment. Can you help me doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works like you want it to changed the `textarea` to a `div`  and i used the height and width of the div to keep a correct height/width http://jsfiddle.net/NkRYY/9/

Comment: Well Thanks for the demo. But then try pressing spacebar while typing in the first line. It doesnt work. One more thing. Div doesnt resize on height change. It does but then on second attempt. Somethings fishy.

Comment: Can you help me doing this way. I start typing from the second line *So that spacebar works* and i can just type one line. That means disable enter button and i set max width so that text shouldn't go beyond it?